# Is there a function $f$ that is a finite sum of functions with finite products of the inputs of $f$ as inputs with this property?

Tags: nt.number-theory, real-analysis

*Note: This question aims to be a generalization of [Is it possible to create a polynomial $p(x)$ with this relation between $p(0)$ and $p(c)$?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/371972/165539) and [Is it possible to create a polynomial $p(x)$ with this relation between $p(0)$ and $p(c)$? -- Part 2](https://mathoverflow.net/q/372665/165539)*

Is there a family of functions $f_n : \mathbb{Z}^n \to \mathbb{N}$ (or at least $\mathbb{Z}^n \to \mathbb{R}$) that takes in $n$ integers $f_n \left(a_1,a_2,a_3,...,a_n \right) = 1$ if $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i=0$ and $0$ otherwise (or at least should be $\leq \epsilon$), such that $f_n$ is a finite linear combination of functions (whose number of terms should grow at most $O(n^d)$ with $d$ not depending on $\epsilon$, $a_i$ or $n$, though an answer that the number of terms is $O(1)$ would be preferred) that take finite products (whose degree is not restricted) of $a_i$ as its inputs? You can assume that $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i \geq 0$.

**Edit:** As @QiaochuYuan pointed out,I should be clear that the terms themselves can change.

Comment: If $f$ really has codomain $\mathbb{Z}^n$ then strictly speaking it doesn't take a *set* of inputs, since some of the inputs may repeat. It would be less confusing to write the standard $f(a_1, \dots a_n)$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Ah, ok. I guess *multiset* would be better.

Comment: Also when you write that the number of terms doesn't depend on $n$ you imply that $n$ is varying and not fixed, so it sounds like you actually want a family of functions $f_n : \mathbb{Z}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. This would be a lot easier if you just told us exactly what you were trying to do.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I'm confused. I gave my motivation above. Also, since the terms shouldn't change, then it shouldn't be *family* of functions: at most, there should be a parameter that depends on $n$.

Comment: You asked two questions about the existence of polynomials satisfying some conditions and were told they didn't exist. Now you're asking a third question about a function satisfying some other conditions. *What do you want these conditions for*? It seems to me that you're putting a lot of effort into writing down unclear conditions without explaining why you want them, and things would be a lot clearer if you just explained what you want them for. Then other people can figure out what conditions you actually need.

Comment: The thing you're doing is called the "XY problem": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem

Comment: There *must* be a family of functions, because you've already said that $n$ is varying. What does it mean for the terms to "not change" as $n$ changes? Is $a_1$ a term that "doesn't change"? What about $\prod_{i=1}^n a_i$? What about $\prod_{i=1}^{\lfloor \frac{n}{3} \rfloor} a_i$? What about $\prod_{i=1}^n a_i^i$?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan The number of terms shouldn't depend on $n$, ie. there should be $2$ terms whether $n=10$ or $n=7$. And yes, $a_i$ can be any integer.

Comment: Yes, that's fine. What about the *terms* themselves?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan The terms can change, there are no restrictions on them.

Comment: So there *is* a family of functions $f_n$. Why did you say there wasn't?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Ok, in that case, then yes, there can be a family of functions. Sorry, I didn't really understand at first.

Comment: Thank you. I am just trying to make sure it's clear what the question is. I edited the question to what I believe you're trying to say.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Is there anything else I should clarify?

Comment: At this point it's clear to me, anyway. I think there isn't such a family of functions. But again, you'd be better off just explaining why you're trying to write down functions satisfying these conditions.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I just want to point out that I edited it to be a bit more lax. I don't know if that makes a solution possible or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no such family of functions for $\epsilon = 0$, and even for $\epsilon_n$ depending on $n$ decaying at a rate to be determined later. I don't know what happens if $\epsilon > 0$ is independent of $n$.

For a multiset of indices $I = \{ i_1, \dots i_n \}$ write $a_I = \prod_{i \in I} a_i$ for the corresponding monomial. We're looking for a family of functions $f_n$ which can be written

$$f_n(a_1, \dots a_n) = \sum_{i=1}^N f_{n, i}(a_{I_{n, i}})$$

for some functions $f_{n, i}$ and some indices $I_{n, i}$, where $N = O(n^d)$ for some absolute constant $d$, such that $f_n(a_1, \dots a_n) = 1$ if $\sum a_i = 0$ and $|f_n(a_1, \dots a_n)| < \epsilon_n$ otherwise.
We'll restrict our attention to the Hamming cube $(a_1, \dots a_n) \in \{ -1, 1 \}^n$ and identify a point in this cube with the subset $S(a) = \{ i : a_i = -1 \}$ of indices with coordinate $-1$. On this cube the monomials $a_I$ behave very simply. Since $a_i^2 = 1$ for $a_i \in \{ -1, 1 \}$ we can restrict our attention to sets of indices $I$ rather than multisets. Then we have

$$a_I = (-1)^{|S(a) \cap I|}$$

hence that $f_{n, i}(a_{I_{n, i}})$ takes on one of two possible values depending on the parity of $|S(a) \cap I|$, and in fact we always just have

$$f(a_I) = \frac{f(1) + f(-1)}{2} + \frac{f(1) - f(-1)}{2} a_I$$

(since this identity holds for $a_I = 1$ or $a_I = -1$). It follows that any function of the form $\sum_{i=1}^N f_{n,i}(a_{I_{n,i}})$, when restricted to the Hamming cube, is a constant plus a linear combination of $N$ functions of the form $a_I$.

The functions $a_I$ are precisely the characters of $\{ -1, 1 \}^n$ regarded as a finite abelian group under pointwise multiplication, and now standard discrete Fourier analysis (the [Hadamard transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_transform)) tells us that any function $f : \{ -1, 1 \}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ on the Hamming cube can be represented uniquely as a linear combination of the $a_I$, with coefficients determined by the inner products

$$\langle f, a_I \rangle = \frac{1}{2^n} \sum_{(a_1, \dots a_n) \in \{ -1, 1 \}^n} f(a_1, \dots a_n) (-1)^{|S(a) \cap I|}.$$

Our strategy from here will be to show that there are infinitely many $n$ such that exponentially many of the Fourier coefficients of $f_n$ don't vanish. The points in the Hamming cube satisfying $\sum a_i = 0$ are exactly the ${n \choose \frac n 2}$ points with the same number of $1$s as $-1$s, and in particular there are no such points if $n$ is odd; from here on we assume that $n$ is even. We have

$$\langle f_n, a_I \rangle = \frac{1}{2^n} \left( \sum_{J \subseteq \{ 1, 2, \dots n \} : |J| = \frac n 2} (-1)^{|J \cap I|} + O(2^n \epsilon) \right).$$

If we replace $I$ by its complement the sum $\sum_{J \subseteq \{ 1, 2, \dots n \} : |J| = n/2} (-1)^{|J \cap I|}$ is multiplied by $(-1)^n$, so to analyze this sum we can assume WLOG that $|I| \le \frac n 2$. By breaking it up depending on the possible values of $|J \cap I|$ we find that

$$\sum_{J \subseteq \{ 1, 2, \dots n \} : |J| = \frac n 2} (-1)^{|J \cap I|} = \sum_{k=0}^{|I|} (-1)^k {|I| \choose k} {n-|I| \choose \frac n 2 - k}.$$

This is the coefficient of $x^{\frac n 2}$ in $(1 - x)^{|I|} (1 + x)^{n-|I|}$, which is a little messy. This product simplifies as much as possible if $|I| = \frac n 2$, where it becomes $(1 - x^2)^{\frac n 2}$, which gives

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\frac n 2} (-1)^k {\frac n 2 \choose k} {\frac n 2 \choose \frac n 2 - k} = \begin{cases} 0 \text{ if } \frac n 2 \equiv 1 \bmod 2 \\ (-1)^{\frac n 4} {\frac n 2 \choose \frac n 4} \text{ if } \frac n 2 \equiv 0 \bmod 2 \end{cases}$$

So from here we assume that $n = 4m$ is divisible by $4$. In this case we've shown that if $\epsilon_{4m} = 0$ then at least ${4m \choose 2m} \sim \frac{2^{4m}}{\sqrt{2\pi m}}$ (by e.g. Stirling's formula) of the Fourier coefficients don't vanish, which is exponentially many in $n$, and in particular more than $N = O(n^d)$ for any $d$. We still get the same conclusion as long as $2^{4m} \epsilon_{4m} < {2m \choose m} \sim \frac{2^{2m}}{\sqrt{\pi m}}$, hence as long as

$$\epsilon_n  = o \left( \frac{1}{2^{ \frac n 2} \sqrt{n}} \right).$$

If we only want to rule out $N = O(1)$ we can instead look at the ${n \choose 2}$ Fourier coefficients where $|I| = 2$; these are all equal to

$${n-2 \choose \frac n 2} - 2 {n-2 \choose \frac n 2 - 1} + {n-2 \choose \frac n 2 - 2}$$

which, after some simplifications I'll save you (I'm a little surprised I don't know an elegant way to do this), is equal to

$$\frac{(2n-1)}{(\frac n 2)(\frac n 2 + 1)} {n-2 \choose \frac n 2 -1} = \Theta \left( \frac{2^n}{n^{\frac 3 2}} \right)$$

so to guarantee that at least ${n \choose 2}$ of the Fourier coefficients are nonzero, which even rules out $N = O(n)$, it suffices to take

$$\epsilon_n = o \left( n^{- \frac 3 2} \right).$$

Similar computations are available for other small values of $|I|$ and using more of these it ought to be possible to improve the bounds.

(Also, if we only want the conclusion for $\epsilon = 0$ there's a similar but much simpler argument given by restricting to the cube $\{ 0, 1 \}^n$ instead and observing that $f_n(a_1, \dots a_n) = \prod_{i=1}^n (1 - a_i)$ on this cube, showing that the monomials $a_I$ for $I$ a set (which are all we need to consider on $\{ 0, 1 \}^n$) are linearly independent, and arguing that this implies that $N \ge 2^n - 1$, for all $n$. But I don't know how to adapt this argument to the $\epsilon_n \neq 0$ case.)

Comment: Actually I wouldn't be surprised if at least for $\epsilon = 0$ there was no such function even with no bound on $N$, but I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: Thank you. I'll wait a day before accepting. In the meantime, +1 from me.

Comment: Since no one else responded, accepted!